# Regex : capitalize non-ascii character after some special character

Tags: javascript, regex

I tried this code to capitalize each non-ascii character or simple letter in a string after a space or a special character like "-", but it doesn't work :

```
var re = /(\b[a-z](?!\s))/g;
var name = "jean-àris-sa ça";
name = name.replace(re, function(x){return x.toUpperCase();});
console.log(name) // Jean-àRis-Sa çà
```

Expected result would be "Jean-Àris-Sa Ça", how can I achieve that ?

Comment: Use python: `'à'.upper()` ,-]

Comment: @Jonas-Byström I forgot to mention it was for javascript but thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```js
console.log(
    "jean-àris-sa ça".replace(/(-|\s+|^)(.)/g, function(_,$1,$2) { 
       return $1 + $2.toUpperCase(); 
    } )
)
```

The `(-|\s+|^)(.)` pattern captures `-` or 1+ whitespaces (or just start of string position, an empty string) into Group 1 and any next char into Group 2 and returns the same string with that char in Group 2 turned into  upper case.

As you may need to upper the first letter while lowering the rest of the letters in the same word, you may need a regex to match all letters. `XRegExp` library can work for you in all browsers:

```js
var regex = XRegExp("(\\pL)(\\pL*)");
console.log( XRegExp.replace("jean-àRiS-sa çA", regex, function(_, $1, $2) {
      return $1.toUpperCase()  + $2.toLowerCase();
   }, "all")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xregexp/3.2.0/xregexp-all.min.js"></script>
```

In the latest Chrome versions that support ECMAScript 2018 you may simply use

```js
console.log( 
   "jean-àRiS-sa çA".replace(/(\p{L})(\p{L}+)/gu, 
         (_, $1, $2) => $1.toUpperCase()  + $2.toLowerCase())
);
```

The `\pL` or `\p{L}` Unicode category matches any letter.

Comment: Works great, except for the first letter which doesn't capitalize, thanks. How can I force lowercase on other characters ?

Comment: @Reda Add `^|` to `(-|\s+)`, `(^|-|\s+)`. I see I did not copy / paste the latest regex I tried, fixed now (added `+` after `\s`).

Comment: Thanks. And if I want to transform "jean-àRiS-sa çA" into "Jean-Àris-Sa Ça" ?

Comment: @Reda What JS environments do you need to support? Do you consider using any third party libraries (like `XRegExp`)?